# Sphinx latex pdf include sub-toctree on subsection page

Tags: latex, python-sphinx, pdflatex, toctree

I have a sphinx documentation project that I use to generate an HTML (`make html`) and a PDF (`make latexpdf`) version of the documentation. I use subdirectories to organize some of the pages. My directory structure is something like this:

```
source/
    index.rst
    page1.rst
    subsection1/
        index.rst
        subpage1.rst
```

I have a toctree specified in both index.rst files:

```
# index.rst
.. toctree::

    page1
    subsection1/index

# subsection1/index.rst
.. toctree::

    subpage1
```

When I generate the HTML the `subsection1/index` page has the TOC list with links to the appropriate pages. When I generate the latex PDF it ignores the sub-toctrees and doesn't print anything, but I would like it to be the same as the HTML.

I don't have a lot of experience with latex and I'm having trouble finding anything online about this so I feel like I'm missing something obvious. I've looked in to `.. contents::` and `.. include::` but of course this doesn't produce what I want with HTML and I was hoping I wouldn't have to have a ton of `.. only::` parts.

Comment: 18 months later this is still impossible. Conditional `.. only:: latex`  `.. include:: Subsubsection.rst` and `.. only:: not latex` `.. toctree::` `Subsubsection` will leave you with an unusable `:ref:` directive as Sphinx is not smart enough to figure out that `.. _Subsubsection:` is effectively contained only once.